# Moment - Change format based on language

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I use moment-timezone js library with a timestamp. Then i apply a timezone to this timestamp, like this

```
import * as moment_timezone from "moment-timezone";

moment_timezone(TIMESTAMP.tz(TIMEZONE))
```

The problem: I need to format based on web language. For example, if user set web in english show in *MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss*, if set in spanish *DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss*

So: What´s is the right way to do that? I tried to import some *local* files but doesn't find right way. I need to do this in a Angular project.

Comment: For multi language applications I would suggest using i18next. It makes everything eaisier

Comment: _"if user set web in english"_ - The format `MM/DD/YYYY` is not a property of the English language. Only a [small part of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) uses that format.

Comment: @Andreas I see United States use this order. Whatever, this is a example, is not only English / Spanish cases available, there is possible other many cases of localizing time in the web.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution to my problem

```
import * as moment_timezone from "moment-timezone";

moment_timezone(TIMESTAMP.tz(TIMEZONE)).format('L')
```